# Missing random icons in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, icons, font-awesome

I was working on my page, when random icons on my page went missing, while others are displaying fine.

The icons that are missing are both some of Wordpress standard, some of Font Awesome and some from different plugins. Same services got some showing as well, even on same pages as showing here:

[Screenshot that shows some missing and some showing icons.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1i9Y.jpg)

[The link for my website](http://dev.woprun.com)

The issue came after i saved a edit on the index page, but the mistake are going on all pages from here.

What have i done wrong and what can i do for avoid the issue?

Thanks

Comment: What to do: Use your browser's developer console and inspect the missing icons.  Report back here what you see.

Comment: As you can read, the comment below solved the issue. There was nothing to see there, they wasn't overwritten in the console

Comment: No, the comment below _did your work_.  _My Comment above_ would equip **you** to troubleshoot in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this style in your active theme `style.css`

```
.fa {    
    font-family: 'FontAwesome' !important;
}
```

`font-family` is overwrite in your theme.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Yes, i'm not sure what happens there. Fixed now!

Comment: Why add this style? How did you sort this out? (You've given this person a fish.  Why not take the opportunity to _teach them how to fish_)

Answer (score -2):

Try adding Font Awesome on you header this may solve that

I check the  tag and it should an if statement for IE9